# Is there a way to disable the animation when changing items?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When changing what item you are holding the handheld model will move down out of frame, it will change to whatever item you have swapped to, then the item will come back up. I need to make it so that the handheld model never moves, it just instantly changes the model. I also need to be able to do this without mods.

Comment: Unsure if this is possible. The tool charge speed can be negated with haste, but it doesn't allow you to remove the tool animation entirely.